# Cordova InAppBrowser Show within the application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I'm trying to hide only the url field of the InAppBrowser. But need to keep close button.

Using following codes I can display the html pages on the full screen with both url field and the close button.

```
window.open(path, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

Or

```
window.open(path, "_blank", 'toolbar=yes', "location=no", "closebuttoncaption=My Button Name");
```

And Using following code I could hide the toolbar at all.

```
window.open(path, '_blank', 'location=no,closebuttoncaption=Close Window');
```

I just want to remove/ hide Url Field and just show the close button and text on the top header. Also If there is a way to put InAppBrowser into a div that also fine.

Comment: you could open an iframe and pointing to the URL you want..

Comment: With the iframe, the problem is back button won't work.

Comment: maybe this helps -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254985/back-and-forward-buttons-in-an-iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it work using [cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser](https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser) custom plugin which is Fork of org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser. It is more themeable and configurable to add some custom actions.