# IFRAME goes to last visited page on click of browser back button

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe(other domain) inside html, In the iframe i have navigation, if i go to another page in iframe then i click the browser's back button, iframe goes to last visited page. i want to get parent html last vesited page on click back button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Back and forward buttons in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254985/back-and-forward-buttons-in-an-iframe)

Comment: Using the provided answer from that question, you just do location replace or href asign with the back location and you will achieve what you want.

Comment: i am accessing iframe src from different domain, iframe.content.. does not work