# Back and Forward Control for an iframe using pure JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I need to create a tightly controlled environment for opening certain pages that need back and forward navigation controls.  I had poked around on here and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254985/back-and-forward-buttons-in-an-iframe) and tried to implement it, but I'm having a problem.

I have the following for the HTML and Javascript going on, assume it's already styled (reusing code from previous project), and JQuery is already listed in the `<head></head>` tags:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="shortcutbar">
            <a id="backBtn" onclick =="iframeBack();"></a>
            <a id="forwardBtn" onclick =="iframeForward();"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="displayContainer">
        <iframe id="display" src="https://website.goes.here/">
        </iframe>
    </div>

    <script>
        function iframeBack() {
            $("#display").contentWindow.history.go(-1);
        }
        function iframeForward() {
            $("#display").contentWindow.history.go(1);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Checking the console, I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "history" of undefined` and it gives both whatever line the function is called in the HTML, and the line of the function itself in the script tags.

I'm at a loss of what isn't working, as everything I've found thus far just refers to some variation of what I've already typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery object doesn't have `contentWindow` property.

You need the underlying element ... `$("#display")[0].contentWindow`.

With that said if the iframe source is from a different origin than the main page you are security restricted from accessing the frame window using javascript

Comment: Does this also apply if you disable web security in the command line arguments?

Comment: Never tried to be honest and is probably a bad idea

Comment: For general use, I agree, but this would be in a tightly regulated environment utilizing intranet sites, never intending to allow the end user to access the internet (I would be setting up a separate instance/session of chrome, so it wouldn't even work with other chrome browsers).  Hence why I would be making my own "UI" and loading web pages in iframes.  At least, what I was reading about that sorta stuff is leading me to believe I should be fine with that kind of setup (I'm using app mode for everything, anyway, so no browser chrome to begin with)

Comment: Try it and see is all I can suggest

Comment: I was able to get a new eror, detailing `blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`  I'm going to mark your answer as the answer, and I'll tinker from here.  Thank you so much!

Comment: It's the cross origin security restriction that provides that error

Comment: I thought `--disable-web-security` was supposed to prevent that, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use postMessage also for secure communication

```js
$("#display").contentWindow.postMessage('back');
```

```js
window.addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  data === "back" && window.history.back()
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Trying this, I get the following error: `Cannot read property 'postMesage' of undefined
    at iframeBack` and I honestly have no clue how to futher tackle this...